# Project Centennial Apps in Hololens Emulator

Tags: wpf, uwp, hololens, desktop-bridge

I have successfully converted my **WPF based .net applications** to **UWP** using Project Centennial. When i upload that project to **Hololens Emulator** using Emulator portal i get the following error.

My UWP app is compiled for **x86** and the emulator version is **10.0.14393.0**

```
Failure reason: Failed to start deployment. 
Failure text: A Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied.(0x80073cfd)
```

Answer (score 3):

HoloLens doesn't support Win32. Your app is Win32 just packed in .appx. It works on PC only and not on other device families. You may add an UWP app to the same package that will serve non-PC devices.

Comment: I have the same problem. Tried with x64 and I get "Failure reason: Failed to start deployment. Failure text: The deployment operation failed because the package targets the wrong processor architecture.
 (0x80073d10)"